# How to make Maven use an ivy repository for dependencies resolution?

Tags: maven, ivy

I know that we can configure ivy to have a Maven repository as a source, but can we do the opposite? 
Or in other words, can I have a Maven based project that will resolve dependencies from an ivy repository?

Is this possible?

thanks in advance!

Comment: Does ivy have it's own repository format? I thought the whole point of ivy was being maven compatible?

Comment: This is a question I'm currently asking but haven't found a satisfactory answer. Have you made any further traction on it?

Answer (score 3):

This [project](https://github.com/evgeny-goldin/maven-plugins/tree/master/ivy-maven-plugin) provides an Ivy plugin for Maven. It works pretty well as I have used it. Kudos to the developer for resolving resolver resolvers!